# Is it possible to import from a CSV into EE 2.7 Relationship fields?

Tags: solspace, solspace-importer

Can Solspace Importer import from a CSV file into relationship fields of channel entries? I have a large number entries with relationships to set up and it would be great if it could be automated.

Examples (can be simple) of how I might do this would be greatly appreciated, including how the CSV file needs to be formatted.